# Difference between and meaning of $(document) and $("body, html")?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move the scroll bar on button click, and I know of two ways to do so.

```js
$(document).scrollTop();
```

```js
$("html, body").animate( { scrollTop:some_pixel_number} , milliseconds );
```

What do $(document) and $("body, html") mean, and how come

`$(document).animate( { scrollTop:some_pixel_number} , milliseconds );`  doesn't work?

Comment: `document` is the parent of `html`, which is the parent of `body`